# Why am I getting 2 errors when I try to run this code relating to string manipulation and if/else statements, this is in java btw, ty

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

class Main 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
```

> Setting up the 2 user inputted phrases

```
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);    

  System.out.println("Enter any phrase: ");
  String userPhrase1 = input.nextLine(); 

  System.out.println("Enter another phrase: ");
  String userPhrase2 = input.nextLine();
```

> //The if/else statements for if the phrases are the same or different

```
  if (userPhrase1.equals(userPhrase2) == true)
  {
   String SameOrDif = "\n" + "Both phrases are the same and"; 
  }
  else 
  {
   String SameOrDif = "\n" + "Both phrases are different and";  
  }
```

> //The if/else statements for the phrase lengths

```
  if (userPhrase1.length() - userPhrase2.length() == 0)
  {
   String stringLength = "the phrases are equal in length"; 
  }
  else if ((userPhrase1.length() - userPhrase2.length()) > 0)
  {
   String stringLength = "the first phrase '" + userPhrase1 + "' is longer than the second phrase '" 
   + userPhrase2 + "'";  
  }
  else 
  {
   String stringLength = "the second phrase '" + userPhrase2 + "' is longer than the first phrase '" 
   + userPhrase1 + "'";  
  }
```

> //This is where I get the errors from

```
  System.out.println(SameOrDif + stringLength + ", and the amount of characters before the first 
  space in the first phrase is " + userPhrase1.indexOf("o") + "and " + userPhrase2.indexOf("k") + " 
  for the second phrase"); 
 }
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Also, `if (userPhrase1.equals(userPhrase2) == true)` is redundant. `if(userPhase1.equals(userPhase2))` will do.

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to access a variable outside of their scope.

Comment: Did you try reading the error messages? Did you understand what the error messages mean? Did you understand where they say the errors are?

Comment: **NOTICE:** My answer solves the issue associated with the last line, but errors still persist, since you are not escaping your characters and using the `+` operator correctly. I would suggest reading up on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error because the variables `SameOrDif` and `stringlength` are not within the scope. You must declare them outside the if statements.

**Also:** You are not printing properly. Like, you are not using `+` operators correctly.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

class Main 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);    

  System.out.println("Enter any phrase: ");
  String userPhrase1 = input.nextLine(); 

  System.out.println("Enter another phrase: ");
  String userPhrase2 = input.nextLine(); 
  String SameOrDif="";
  String stringLength="";
 if (userPhrase1.equals(userPhrase2) == true)
  {
   SameOrDif = "\n" + "Both phrases are the same and"; 
  }
  else 
  {
   SameOrDif = "\n" + "Both phrases are different and";  
  }
  if (userPhrase1.length() - userPhrase2.length() == 0)
  {
   stringLength = "the phrases are equal in length"; 
  }
  else if ((userPhrase1.length() - userPhrase2.length()) > 0)
  {
   stringLength = "the first phrase '" + userPhrase1 + "' is longer than the second phrase '" 
   + userPhrase2 + "'";  
  }
  else 
  {
   stringLength = "the second phrase '" + userPhrase2 + "' is longer than the first phrase '" 
   + userPhrase1 + "'";  
  }
  System.out.println(SameOrDif + stringLength + ", and the amount of characters before the first 
  space in the first phrase is " + userPhrase1.indexOf("o") + "and " + userPhrase2.indexOf("k") +  
  "for the second phrase"); 
 }
}
```